# JQuery - how to determine if a dom element is "hidden"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have some logic that relies on JQuery's `element.width()` method. The logic is failing on me sometimes. I noticed that it is only failing when the element is hidden (inside a bootstrap collapsible element). I looked in the docs and they say:

> The value reported by .width() is not guaranteed to be accurate when
>   the element or its parent is hidden. To get an accurate value, ensure
>   the element is visible before using .width(). jQuery will attempt to
>   temporarily show and then re-hide an element in order to measure its
>   dimensions, but this is unreliable and (even when accurate) can
>   significantly impact page performance. This show-and-rehide
>   measurement feature may be removed in a future version of jQuery.

So I know my problem. My plan is to check if the element is "hidden" and if so, instead of executing the logic right away, I will search for the collapsible parent and subscribe the logic to the `shown.bs.collapse` event.

My issue is how to check if the element is considered "hidden" by JQuery's width method (as mentioned in the docs). Is it as simple as:

```
element[0].style.display == "none"
```

I would like a check that captures all cases.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/visibility-filter-selectors/

Comment: Combine the `:hidden` selector and the `.is()` method -> `$(element).is(':hidden')` (returns a boolean).

Answer (score 0):

I believe jQuery uses this logic:

```
$(element).is(":visible")
```